# Avoid updating nested lists in for loop

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a Python program that I want to create different lists in a for loop and then store these list in another list to create an array. I take one input list, modify it and append it to storage list, and then repeat. My problem is that when I update the next list in the loop all lists in the array also gets updated, so I end up with an array containing multiple identical lists.

```
array = []    
road = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    array.append(road)

    for i in range(0,len(road)-1):
        if road[i] == 1:
            road[i] = 0
            road[i+1] = 1
        print(road)
        array.append(road)
```

The print(road) yields exactly what I want namely

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

but the array after the last iteration contains

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

and after the first iteration

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What can I do to stop the array from updating when I'm changing the list in the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.append(road)
```

Change this to

```
array.append(road[:])
```

to append a *copy* of the list. That way you have multiple different lists appended rather than the same list object appended repeatedly.

Comment: To be specific, it appends a _shallow_ copy of the `list`; that said, since the `list` contains immutable objects (`int`), this is fine. If `road` was a `list` of `list`s though, you'd want to use `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is `array.append(road)`. This is creating a shallow list, which is a clone of the original. This gets changed when you change the others.

To avoid this, you need a new list. To make this, you can use `[:]` as John suggests, or you can use `list()`, which can be easier to read - and more obvious what it does.

So, instead of `array.append(road)` use `array.append(list(road))`.